# Resetting values based on time MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

At the moment I am trying to make my java program to reset some values. The trigger to resetting these values would be the start of a new day. So for example, if the date is 24/1/2015, I open the program to do my stuff and close the program. If I open the program on 24/1/2015, it will not reset the program. However if I open the program at 25/1/2015 it will reset the values in the MySQL database.

So. How do I make a validation for the time/date to reset the values in the database?

Comment: Roy, do you have an idea where you are going to store the date you reset the values?  Somewhere you are going to have to persist this value, and retrieve it later for comparison.  Perhaps a property file, or a table?

Comment: yes i have a table of values that stores the values that i want to change

Comment: Does this table include the date you changed the values?  In your example, this would store 24/1/2015.

Comment: yes it does store the values with the date as well.

Comment: Right.  So when you invoke the program, you read in the date?  Are you looking for the java code to compare today's date with that date?

Comment: yes i am trying to compare the data from java code to the one stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getTodayAtMidnight() method to calculate the next valid time you can set values.  Store this value in the table.  Then use 'now.after(nextSetDate)' to see if it returns 'true'.  If so, you can reset the values, and store the next date.  If it returns false, you are still at the same date and should not reset values.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date nextSetDate = getTodayAtMidnight();
    System.out.println(nextSetDate);
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.after(nextSetDate));
}
public static Date getTodayAtMidnight() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zone. The JVM’s current default time zone is applied, but that default can vary – even during runtime(!).

Comment: What is the correct approach to overcome this issue?

Comment: Correct approach is to **always specify a time zone** rather than implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone.

Comment: Another problem is that this code assumes the first moment of a day is the time `00:00:00.0`. Not always true because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid using the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Use the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

In java.time, use the `LocalDate` class for a date-only value when you do not need time-of-day or time zone. While time zone is not stored within a `LocalDate` note that you must specify a time zone to determine "today". The date is not simultaneously the same around the world, as a new day dawns earlier in the east. So specify your desired/expected time zone. If omitted the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. That default can change at any time, even at runtime(!), so better to explicitly specify the time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

In MySQL, use its [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) type to store a date-only value. Use `java.sql.Date` to retrieve/store such values. Immediately convert into a java.time type.

```
LocalDate stored = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Compare by calling `isEqual`, `isBefore`, or `isAfter`. Your Question is not clear, so I am not sure which you need for your business logic.

```
if( stored.isBefore( today ) ) {
    java.sql.Date dateToStore = java.sql.Date.valueOf( today );
    // … store today’s date in database.
}
```

If need be, you may convert this `LocalDate` date-only into a date-time, getting the first moment of a day appropriate to some particular time zone. Be aware that a day does *not* always start with the time `00:00:00.0` because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String representation of the date-time value in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = zdt.toString(); // Ex: 2016-12-03T00:00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]
```